# Jasper quits PDF generation with Error while loading available fonts

Tags: jasper-reports, netweaver

On my local jBoss machine, generation of PDFs works fine. However, when I try publish (so far it seems so) basically anything on NetWeaver deployed same code of application, generation crashes with this error:

```
08-06-18:00:46:45 [HTTP Worker [@802492534]] ERROR [JRStyledTextParser:paveljanicek] Error while loading available fonts
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.<init>(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.getInstance(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:131)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.ensureFontExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:80)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:130)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:86)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:111)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:219)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:234)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:134)
```

Worst part is, I cannot think about how to reproduce this error. This is what I already checked on target machine:

- Fonts are installed and accessible to the app
- jasperreports-fonts.jar is accessible to the Jasper reports

On my local machine:

- PDF does generate with warnings (I am using old attributes like issplitAllowed or border)
- If fonts are deleted, local instance crashes with different error (mostly "Fonts are not available to the JVM")

Does anyone has any idea what to check, where to look?

Comment: The error is probably caused by the SAX parser used in the NetWeaver environment not knowing about the http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl feature (which is set by JasperReports).  I don't know anything about NetWeaver, but try to include a Xerces (2) jar in your application.

Comment: As it seems, it is caused by the NW. There is patch for that inside NW, so we will try to upgrade target machine over night. Will let you know about the results

Answer (score 0):

NW uses default XML parser, which doesn't support setting security feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl". This feature is set by Jasper style sheet parser from version 6.4.2

Quick solution is to use different XML parser, which supports mentioned feature by setting system property "`javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`" to proper XML parser in NW properties.

Definitely the issue is on NW side.

However, I did find an Oracle equivalent XML parser (still based on Xerces) that is more forgiving when setting XML features:  `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl`.

This parser comes with the Oracle JVM used in the project so we do not need to add an additional library and is actually the default parser based on JavaDocs.

Netweaver JVM decided to use `oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory` as default instead.